# extjs rowEditing plugin startEdit always return false

Tags: extjs, grid, sencha-architect

Here is my code to insert an editable item to grid

```
var grid = button.up('#gpDiabeticsSelfAssessment'),
store = grid.getStore(),
record = Ext.create('HMETRIX.model.DiabeticsSelfAssessment', {}),
plugin = grid.editingPlugin;
store.insert(0,record);
plugin.startEdit(record,0);
```

It's not working. Not even double clicking the row enables editing.

Whats wrong with this.

Answer (score 0):

Try This...

```
    plugin = grid.editingPlugin;
    plugin.stopEditing();

    //add our new record as the first row, select it
    grid.store.insert(0, record);
    grid.getView().refresh();
    grid.getSelectionModel().selectRow(0);

    //start editing our new User
    plugin.startEditing(0);
```

Comment: Am getting an error as
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'stopEditing'

Comment: Am getting an error as
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'stopEditing'

I changed to canselEdit and is fine but another error 

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'selectRow'